# VBA Intellisense not activating

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm unsure if this is normal behavior, but I have the following interface and class that implements the interface.

Interface **IFactoryPart**:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public xDim As Double
Public yDim As Double
Public Gauge As Byte
Public HoleData As Collection
```

Class **Blank**:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Implements IFactoryPart

'from interface
Public txDim As Double
Public tyDim As Double
Public tGauge As Byte
Public tHoleData As Collection

'class specific
'   -nothing yet


Public Property Get IFactoryPart_xDim() As Double
    IFactoryPart_xDim = txDim
End Property

Public Property Let IFactoryPart_xDim(ByVal newxDim As Double)
    txDim = newxDim
End Property
```

When I type the following, intellisense doesn't activate:

```
Dim inputBlank As New Blank

'doesn't activate when i type the period
inputBlank.xDim = 1
```

I can't seem to find a reason why it's not working, so maybe I wrote something incorrectly?

Comment: What is `Hole`?  Is it another class you haven't shown?

Comment: Woops, I added the incorrect last line of code. I'll edit it when I get back to the office in a few minutes.

Comment: @Brian M Stafford edit was made

Comment: To answer your question, this is not normal behavior.  When I cut and paste your code, Intellisense works fine.  Perhaps you should try restarting Access?

Comment: Good idea; I'll try that when I get back in the office tomorrow morning.

Comment: Make sure you have no compile errors anywhere (Debug -> Compile).

Comment: It seems to work now; I guess restarting fixed it. Thanks guys.